# Integrating python code in MVC application in asp.Net

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing an MVC application in asp.net and have a python file 'clientcheck.py' by which the client sends an image/video to the server (also written in Python). My question is, how do I integrate the python code in the MVC application. I'm running Visual Studio 2012.
Also, the python code when running separately works completely fine. I have also installed IronPython.
Would really appreciate the help. I'm new here so please don't mind if my style of question asking is not up to the mark.

#### Code

```
import socket,os
import sys
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(("192.168.1.21", 5050))
k = ' '
size = 1024

while(1):
    print ("Do you want to Send a \n1.Image\n2.Video\n")
    k = raw_input()
    #k=k.encode('utf-8')
    client_socket.send(k)
    print (k)    
    k = int (k)
  #  if(k == 1):
    
   #     print ("Enter file name\n")
   #     data = input()
   #     data=data.encode('utf-8')
   #     fp = open(data,'r')
   #     print ("Opening file - ",data)
   #     fp = open(data,'r')
   #     strng = fp.read()
   #     size = os.path.getsize(data)
   #     size = str(size)
   #     client_socket.send(size)
   #     print ("")
   #     client_socket.send (strng)
   #     client_socket.close()
   #     print ("Data sent successfully")
       


    if (k==1 or k==2):
        print ("Enter file name of the image with extentsion (example: filename.jpg,filename.png or if a video file then filename.mpg etc) - ")
        fname = raw_input()
        
        fname1 = 'Received_'+fname
        fname = """C:/Users/Mehmoo/Desktop/Python/"""+fname
        
        print ("Opening file - ",fname)
        #fname1=fname1.encode('utf-8')
        client_socket.send(fname1)
        
        img = open(fname,'rb')
        while True:
            strng = img.read(1024)
            print('Sending data...')
            if not strng:
                break
            client_socket.send(strng)
        img.close()
        print ("Data sent successfully")
        exit()
```